# Scores wont update correctly

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

My score displays in the screen and it updates for a second and then it goes back to 0, I have analyzed every part of my code and can't find where it is going wrong.

```
def collisions(score,screen, player, mobs, bullets, ai_settings,  all_sprites, meteor_imgs):
    hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, bullets, True, True)
    for hit in hits:
        score += 50
        m = Mob(ai_settings, meteor_imgs)
        all_sprites.add(m)
        mobs.add(m)
    draw_text(screen, "SCORE: " + str(score) , 20, 0,0, ai_settings)

    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, False)
    if hits:
        sys.exit()
```

This is my main loop:

```
def run_game(): 

    score = 0
    gf.add_mobs(ai_settings, all_sprites, mobs, meteor_imgs)

    while True:

        clock.tick(FPS)

        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, all_sprites, background, background_rect) 
        gf.check_events(player, all_sprites, bullets)   
        gf.collisions(score, screen, player, mobs, bullets, ai_settings, all_sprites, meteor_imgs)  
        all_sprites.update()        


        pygame.display.flip()


run_game()
```

The score should be adding up 50 each time I shoot down a mob but it is constantly going back to zero.

Comment: Please, fix the indentation.

Comment: Are you calling `collisions` multiple times?

Comment: @EliKorvigo just once in the main loop

Comment: Can you show the loop? P.S. your indentation is still broken all over the place and although I haven't downvoted your question, I still urge you to fix it. Indentation is critical in Python.

Comment: @EliKorvigo i edited it so that i show my main loop , i think indentation is fixed as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def run_game(): 
    score = 0
    ...
    while True:
        ...
        gf.collisions(score, screen, player, mobs, bullets, ai_settings, all_sprites, meteor_imgs)  
    ...
```

As I've suspected, you are calling `collisions` multiple times in a loop. That's why each time the function is called, it gets `score = 0`. When you update `score` inside `collisions`

```
def collisions(score, ...):
    ...
    for hit in hits:
        score += 50
    ...
```

it only happens locally (inside the function), because integers are immutable. And that's a good thing, because relying on mutable global variables inside functions is not a good programming practice in the long run. Returning the score is a better alternative.

In module gf.py

```
def collisions(score, ...):
    ...
    for hit in hits:
        score += 50
    ...
    return score
```

In your main module

```
import gf

...

def run_game(): 
    score = 0
    ...
    while True:
        ...
        score = gf.collisions(
            score, screen, player, mobs, 
            bullets, ai_settings, all_sprites, meteor_imgs
        )  
    ...
```

P.S.

Calling `sys.exit` inside `collisions` is not a good thing to do either. You'd better keep all your functions as pure as possible and move all stateful control flow logic into the main loop.

Comment: I thought that if I returned a value from the functions the other things I used it for would stop working, now I know. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexanderGoussasEgas if `return` is the last thing that happens inside a function it affects nothing (because all functions `return None` by default), unless you actually expect and want the function to return `None`.